# vb.net keeps removing decimal in equation

Tags: vb.net, variables, decimal, equation

I have a variable whose value comes to a down to a number which uses a decimal place. example 257.85 however when i further process this value in the following equation it removes the decimal and the number becomes 25785 which is incorrect.

The equation used in vb.net:

```
Dim ITEM2b As Integer = DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value '<--This case senario the value came to 257.85

Dim ITEM15 As Integer

If item1B = 4 Then
    ITEM15 = ((ITEM2b / 10) - (ITEM5b / 10)) / 2
ElseIf item1B = 3 Then
    ITEM15 = ((ITEM2b / 10) - (ITEM5b / 10)) / 3
    'MsgBox(ITEM2b & " " & ITEM5b) '<-- This line helped reveal the problem 
    'ITEM15 = ((257.85 / 10) - (50 / 10)) / 3
ElseIf item1B = 2 Then
    ITEM15 = ((ITEM2b / 10) - (ITEM5b / 10)) / 2
End If
```

I have tried to set the Item2b variable as Integer, string and Double but to no avail!

Comment: Have you tried setting is as `Decimal` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ITEM2b As Integer = DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value '<--This case senario the value came to 257.85

Dim ITEM15 As Integer
```

You are passing the value to an integer which will result for the value to remove it's decimal places.

Try using ***Double***.

```
Dim ITEM2b As Double= DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value '<--This case senario the value came to 257.85

Dim ITEM15 As Double
```

Comment: I have used double and decimal but it still keeps removing it... Im thinking dose the value change because of the datagridview? hoever i also tried changing the equational line too ITEM15 = ((Convert.ToDouble(ITEM2b) / 10) - (ITEM5b / 10)) / 3 but again it fails

Comment: Strange is, that the returned result is 25785 and not 258, which should be returned in case the variable is Integer.

Comment: @Crush Sundea I canged Item15 as double also... now i have the wrong result with a decimal (the correct result should be 6.9) the incorect answer keeps showing as 857 after your sugestion i get 857.833 same for decimal

Comment: There.. you said it. It is now in _Double_ and showing the decimals. Your answer is not what you excepted? Try checking the your formula. :)

Comment: I have i have also as you can see in my original code tried it without varibles 'ITEM15 = ((257.85 / 10) - (50 / 10)) / 3 that works fine

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the assignment of the value from the DataGrid. Then highlight _DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value_. Now press _Shift+F9_. What's the value?

Comment: This problem can be easily found by running a **Breakpoint**.

Comment: yeah I have just checked the result returns as 257.85

Comment: Seems weird. Put a breakpoint in  `ITEM15 = ((ITEM2b / 10) - (ITEM5b / 10)) / 3`. Highlight the formula. _Shift+F9_ again. (This is getting long... :D)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103932/discussion-between-crush-sundae-and-abandond-acount).